# Trying to create a Sql Cube Query Not having any luck

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation

I have an OLTP database that contains 400 million rows.   I am trying to create a SQL query that produces results something similar to this:

```
Count(*)        DateRange Using DateDiff
1 million           > 10 yrs 
2 million           > 20 yrs 
10 Million          > 50 yrs
```

And so on.

I create a query something like this:

```
 select count(*) , DateDiff( year , Start_date , End_Date) 
    group by column
    having DateDiff > 10 

    Union 

    select count(*) , DateDiff( year , Start_date , End_Date) 
    group by column
    having DateDiff > 20
```

I believe there is a Cube function that I can use but I cannot seem to get that query right.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is your query failing currently?

Comment: It is not exactly failing ...it's taking forever to return results.   The way I see it I am having to make several passes on a table that contains 400 million rows.

Comment: So you need to optimize it. I'm writing an answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Having a query with aggregates on a full table takes a while. You are having n such queries, which is n times slower than if you had a single query. So, logically, we conclude that the goal is to convert your `union`-based query concatenation into a single query. And luckily it is achievable (I hope this is legal syntax in SQL Server, in which I didn't work for a few years, but I'm sure the idea can be used):

```
select yourcolumn
sum(
case
    when DateDiff( year , Start_date , End_Date) > 10 then 1
    else 0
end) as yrs10,
sum(
case
    when DateDiff( year , Start_date , End_Date) > 20 then 1
    else 0
end) as yrs20,
sum(
case
    when DateDiff( year , Start_date , End_Date) > 50 then 1
    else 0
end) as yrs50
from yourtable
group by yourcolumn;
```

So, this will create a single record for each possible value of `yourcolumn` and in that record you will have a field that will identify your `yourcolumn` value and a field for each of your time interval-based aggregation.